# Pandas sort but maintain in group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

For example i have df with such columns :

```
Area     Prod     Count
  A           A1          5
  A           A2          4
  B           B1          5
  B           B2         11
  B           B3         15
  C           C1          5
```

I want to apply sort based on occurrences, then sort by `Count`
For instance after sorting the df should look like this:

```
Area     Prod     Count
  B           B3         15
  B           B2         11
  B           B1          1
  A           A1          5
  A           A2          4
  C           C1          5
```

Since `B` have 3 rows it is sort first, then inside `B` the `Prod` is sort by `Count`
I tried using `df.groupby('area', 'prod').sort_values(by=('Count'), ascending=False))` didn't able to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is create index by counts and then use it for sorting:

```
df.index = df['Area'].map(df['Area'].value_counts()).rename('idx')

print (df.sort_values(['idx','Count'], ascending=False))
    Area Prod  Count
idx                 
3      B   B3     15
3      B   B2     11
3      B   B1      5
2      A   A1      5
2      A   A2      4
1      C   C1      5

df = df.sort_values(['idx','Count'], ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  Area Prod  Count
0    B   B3     15
1    B   B2     11
2    B   B1      5
3    A   A1      5
4    A   A2      4
5    C   C1      5
```

---

But problem should be if there is multiple same counts, added `D` group with length `3`:

```
print (df)
  Area Prod  Count
0    A   A1      5
1    A   A2      4
2    B   B1      5
3    B   B2     11
4    B   B3     15
5    C   C1      5
6    D   A1     50
7    D   A2     40
8    D   B1      5
```

Then create index by counts:

```
df.index = df['Area'].map(df['Area'].value_counts()).rename('idx')
print (df)
    Area Prod  Count
idx                 
2      A   A1      5
2      A   A2      4
3      B   B1      5
3      B   B2     11
3      B   B3     15
1      C   C1      5
3      D   A1     50
3      D   A2     40
3      D   B1      5
```

But if sorting like first solution are mixed rows:

```
print (df.sort_values(['idx','Count'], ascending=False))
    Area Prod  Count
idx                 
3      D   A1     50
3      D   A2     40
3      B   B3     15
3      B   B2     11
3      B   B1      5
3      D   B1      5
2      A   A1      5
2      A   A2      4
1      C   C1      5
```

Solution is add column `Area` for sorting, e.g. all descending:

```
print (df.sort_values(['idx','Area','Count'], ascending=False))
    Area Prod  Count
idx                 
3      D   A1     50
3      D   A2     40
3      D   B1      5
3      B   B3     15
3      B   B2     11
3      B   B1      5
2      A   A1      5
2      A   A2      4
1      C   C1      5
```

Or you can sort `Area` by ascending:

```
print (df.sort_values(['idx','Area','Count'], ascending=[False, True, False]))
    Area Prod  Count
idx                 
3      B   B3     15
3      B   B2     11
3      B   B1      5
3      D   A1     50
3      D   A2     40
3      D   B1      5
2      A   A1      5
2      A   A2      4
1      C   C1      5
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the details explanation. At first, before your edited version I was having trouble when it has the same number of rows. Glad that you explained in details regarding this. Thanks!